# Количество строк в WPF контроле

Tags: wpf

Имеется `String`, который необходимо вывести в `TextBlock`. Если строка не помещается по длине в `TextBlock`, то строку необходимо нарезать на части.

Как вычислить, помещается строка в `TextBlock` или нет? А если нет, то на сколько частей ее нужно разделить?
Необходим метод, который на вход получит `TextBlock.ActualWidth` и `String`, а на выходе из метода вернется или сама строка, если она помещается, или ее части, которые помещаются в `TextBlock` с указанным `ActualWidth`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, наверное в *WPF* есть специальный метод, но не могу найти.

> какая ваша настоящая задача, есть хороший шанс, что она решается по-другому.

В ListBox вывожу текст. Строки разной длины. Если строка по длине не вписывается в ListBox, то появляется ScrollBar. Это нельзя допустить. Но включать TextWrapping тоже нельзя, потому что строки станут разной высоты. Поэтому надо нарезать строки на части, которые полностью умещаются по длине в ListBox.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TextLines}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding TextLine}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Вы делаете явно что-то не то. Вам не должно быть нужно такое. Расскажите, какая ваша настоящая задача, есть хороший шанс, что она решается по-другому. Ручное разбиение на строки не нужно практически никогда.

Comment: А свойство `TextBlock.TextWrapping` не подойдет? Ничего считать самому не надо. Если строка не поместится в контейнер, то будет выполнен перенос

Comment: А почему вы выводите текст в `ListBox`, а не в один большой `TextBlock`?

Comment: Потому что нужно выводить в ListBox

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете получить длину строки следующим образом:

```
private int StringLen(string candidate)
{
    var formattedText = new FormattedText(
        candidate,
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture,
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        new Typeface(this.textBlock.FontFamily, this.textBlock.FontStyle, this.textBlock.FontWeight, this.textBlock.FontStretch),
        this.textBlock.FontSize,
        Brushes.Black);

    return formattedText.Width;
}
```

А потом используя `TextBlock.ActualWidth` разделить удобным для вас образом.

Comment: Значит candidate - вся моя строка. Но formattedText.Width в пикселях или юнитах? А мне надо получить длину в char